# Doubts about ddply function in R

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to do an equivalent `group by` summary in `R` through the `plyr` function named `ddply`. I have a data frame which have three columns (say `id`, `period` and `event`). Then, I'd like to count the times each `id` appears in the data frame (`count(*)... group by id` with `SQL`) and get the last element of each `id` corresponding to the column `event`.

Here an example of what I have and what I'm trying to obtain:

```
  id period event #original data frame
  1      1     1
  2      1     0
  2      2     1
  3      1     1
  4      1     1
  4      1     0

  id  t  x #what I want to obtain
  1   1  1
  2   2  1
  3   1  1
  4   2  0
```

This is the simple code I've been using for that:

```
 teachers.pp<-read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/alda/teachers_pp.csv", sep=",", header=T) # whole data frame
 datos=ddply(teachers.pp,.(id),function(x) c(t=length(x$id), x=x[length(x$id),3])) #This is working fine.
```

Now, I've been reading [The Split-Apply-Combine Strategy for Data
Analysis](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) and it is given an example where they employed an equivalent syntax to the one I put below:

```
  datos2=ddply(teachers.pp,.(id), summarise, t=length(id), x=teachers.pp[length(id),3]) #using summarise but the result is not what I want.
```

This is the data frame I get using `datos2`

```
  id  t  x
  1   1  1
  2   2  0
  3   1  1
  4   1  1
```

So, my question is: why is this result different from the one I get using the first piece of code, I mean `datos1`? What am I doing wrong?

It is not clear for me when I have to use `summarise` or `transform`. Could you tell me the correct syntax for the `ddply` function?

Comment: Using your second version, my column for t reads: 1, 2, 1, 2. A typo or is that actually what your machine prints out?

Comment: No, that's the result my pc is printing out. 1,2,1,1. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `summarise`, stop referencing the original data frame. Instead, just write expressions in terms of the column names.

You tried this:

```
ddply(teachers.pp,.(id), summarise, t=length(id), x=teachers.pp[length(id),3])
```

when what you probably wanted was something more like this:

```
ddply(teachers.pp,.(id), summarise, t=length(id), x=tail(event,1))
```